# switch case not working properly in C

Tags: c

In my program there is a minor problem.

When I press 2 or 3 or 4 it will display the properly but after that when I 
press the a or b or c etc., it will display previous one result instead of print the  Invalid option.

How can I fix this?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    typedef struct vehicle
    {
    char name[100];
    char lice_no[25];
    int vehicle_type;
    char cmpny_name[100];
    int menu_year;
     }record;

    int main(void)
    {
    int i,choice;
    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    char oname[100];
    record det,det1;
    int recsize;
    char c;

    fp1 = fopen("record.dat" , "r+");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
        fp1 = fopen("record.dat" , "w+");
        if(fp1 == NULL)
        {
            printf("error in opening file : \n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    recsize = sizeof(det);

    do
    {
        printf("\t\"enter the choice\"\n");

        printf("1 : adding the record\n");
        printf("2 : delete the record\n");
        printf("3 : editing the record\n");
        printf("4 : display the record\n");
        printf("5 : exit the program\n");


        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d" , &choice);
        scanf("%c" , &c);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1 :
            {
                    printf("In this add logic\n")
                break;
            }
            case 2 :
            {
                printf("In this case delete logic\n");
                break;
            }
            case 3 :
            {
                printf("In this case edit logic\n");
                                break;
            }
            case 4 :
            {
                printf("display logic\n");
                break;
            }
            case 5 :
            {
                printf("exit logic\n");
                break;
            }
            default :
            {
                printf("\"Invalid option\"\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c" , &c);` What is this for? You never use it.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` you *cannot* do that. `fflush` is not for INPUT streams. You cannot 'flush' an INPUT stream. `fflush` is for OUTPUT streams (e.g. to make sure whatever you print gets sent to the terminal)

Comment: Actually the code works as expected as long as you add a `;` after the `In this add logic` line.

Comment: @MikeKwan - Could be. My comments are comments, not answers :)

Comment: @MikeKwan - There is definitely something weird about the program. And *now* that I know what it is, I have posted an answer. Good catch though, the semicolon!

Comment: The problem is that you're using `scanf()`.  It is fiendishly tricky to get it right.  When the user types a letter, the `scanf()` for choice fails (you should check the result of every `scanf()` to ensure it worked, and you should handle errors) so the value is unchanged.  The second `scanf()` is designed to pick up the newline, but when a letter was typed, it picks up the letter instead.  If you're on Windows, `getch()` is a reasonable option.  Alternatively, use `fgets()` to read a line and then `sscanf()` to parse it.  That's usually the more robust strategy.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Actually, since it appears that the OP wants to input a single character. I would go with a simple solution provided by the C standard: [fgetc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fgetc.html).

Comment: @ArjunShankar: `fgetc()` won't read anything until you type newline, and then you have to deal with skipping the newline.  Certainly, it is feasible; it would not be what I'd recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are getting the numbers into Choice, and the chars into c.
but you are only using the Choice var in the switch, you are never checking the C var.

So essentially, if you hit a letter it is storing it in the C var, and then using the old value in Choice again.

Comment: This makes sense to me. The OP has a slightly weird program, and you seem to have understood what they want correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, one of the things wrong in your codes is the:

```
scanf("%c" , &c);
```

because, the scanf function requires the user to press the enter key before it could store the character to its respective variable.

**So if the compiler reads the line:**

```
scanf("%c" , &c);
```

it reads your input, PLUS, the ENTER.
Thus forcing the scanf function to store your input, PLUS, the ENTER, into your character variable.

It would be better if you would use getche() or getch() instead of using scanf() function, and please do not ever use:

```
scanf("%c" , &c);
```

because it would generate an error.

---

**Sample of usage of getche() or getch() function:**

```
c=getche(); //waits for a keypress and stores it on a variable
c=getch();  //waits for a keypress and stores it on a variable
```

the difference between the two is that the getche() displays your keypress while the getch() does not.

---

Note: Do not forget to put

```
#include<conio.h>
```

---

Added info:
If you still want to go on using the scanf() function just make sure that you declare your favorite variable as:

```
char c[20];
```

then you may use:

```
scanf("%s", &c);
```

but your variable, can only hold up to 19 characters, as how we declared on your character array.

And the summary is do not use:

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

because, it can affect your other scanf() functions. :)

---

SOLUTION(Spoiler Warning):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct vehicle
{
    char name[100];
    char lice_no[25];
    int vehicle_type;
    char cmpny_name[100];
    int menu_year;
}record;

int main(void)
{
    int i; //removed choice from int
    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    char oname[100];
    record det,det1;
    char choice; //made the variable choice a character
    int recsize;
    char c;

fp1 = fopen("record.dat" , "r+");
if(fp1 == NULL)
{
    fp1 = fopen("record.dat" , "w+");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("error in opening file : \n");
        return -1;
    }
}
recsize = sizeof(det);

do
{
    printf("\t\"enter the choice\"\n");

    printf("1 : adding the record\n");
    printf("2 : delete the record\n");
    printf("3 : editing the record\n");
    printf("4 : display the record\n");
    printf("5 : exit the program\n");


    fflush(stdin);
    choice = getche(); // or getch()

    switch(choice) //changed the target character
    {
        case '1' : //changed the case from 1 to '1'
        {
                printf("In this add logic\n");
                break;
        }
        case '2' : //changed the case from 2 to '2'
        {
            printf("In this case delete logic\n");
            break;
        }
        case '3' : //changed the case from 3 to '3'
        {
            printf("In this case edit logic\n");
                            break;
        }
        case '4' : //changed the case from 4 to '4'
        {
            printf("display logic\n");
            break;
        }
        case '5' : //changed the case from 5 to '5'
        {
            printf("exit logic\n");
            break;
        }
        default :
        {
            printf("\"Invalid option\"\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
while(1);
return 0;
}
```

---

You can also use switch to compare characters. Just change the values

```
case 1:
```

to

```
case '1':
```

Comment: Actually, this can go horribly wrong. What if the user inputs 100 characters and you use a 20 character buffer? `scanf` will write to memory addresses that must not be touched. This will probably cause a runtime error.

Comment: @ArjunShankar that's why i specified that it could hold up to 19 characters, don't worry, i'll update it now. :)

Comment: @ArjunShankar thanks for that idea. I already updated it to a much better solution.

Comment: While the OP may be okay with this answer, using 'conio.h' is usually a bad idea. As far as the C standard is concerned, there is no such thing as `conio.h`. Many machines do not *have* a `conio.h`. Moreover, definitions in `conio.h` also have slightly differing behavior based on which compiler shipped it. You can read why here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h

Comment: Hmm, no wonder others does not know about it. I think I'm a bit primitive in this language. I'll do another solution for this one, but it would be much more longer.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` returns you a value, which you don't check.

When used with `%d` specifier - it should parse an integer. Since you enter a non-integer value - `scanf` returns you an error code, and `choice` is unchanged

Answer (score 0):

It's because in c when you are reading characters as integers (scanf("%d" , &choice);) it takes the ascii code of the characters for example a = 97, b = 98 c = 99 d = 100 if you want to read a as 1 b as 2 etc you will have to add some extra code that tells the programme if the number is equal to the ascii code of a b c d or e subtract it with 96 so you get 1,2,3..

Comment: Nope, the choice is read as "%d", and it will be an integer, the problem exists elsewhere.